# What class to overload to add domain parameter to ASP.NET MVC 5.1 Attribute Routing (multitenant mvc app)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributerouting

I basically have one MVC project which respond different apps to multiple domains :
 - http://www.mydomain1.com
 - http://www.mydomain2.com
etc

I'm looking to extend MVC 5.1 Attribute Routing to handle domain name on declaration level, so I can write on my class controller something like this :

[RoutePrefix(domain = "www.mydomain1.com", prefix = "account")]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can overload any methods of `MapMvcAttributeRoutes` in `RouteCollectionAttributeRoutingExtensions` class to add your domain parameter.
In ASP.NET MVC, the `MapMvcAttributeRoutes` extension method has been added when you want to use `Attribute Routing` like below:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
 {
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
            // ....
 }
```

The MapMvcAttributeRoutes method is in the RouteCollectionAttributeRoutingExtensions class:

```
public static class RouteCollectionAttributeRoutingExtensions
{
    public static void MapMvcAttributeRoutes(this RouteCollection routes);
    public static void MapMvcAttributeRoutes(this RouteCollection routes, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver);
}
```

Because the `RouteCollectionAttributeRoutingExtensions` class and `MapMvcAttributeRoutes` methods are `static` types,
you can NOT inherit from the class, also you can NOT overload the methods either.